# Bulk database update using JAVA

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, jdbc, ibatis

We are using oracle as a database , we have 3 lack records in the database .
I want to read each row and i have to update the row based on some criteria , what is the fastest way to achieve this through JAVA?

Comment: Maybe outside the application, restarting it (to prevent false caching).  Non-transactional, as much in the databse. Possibly with a temp table with old value + newly calculated value so a safe update is possible.

Answer (score 0):

You can refer to the batch processing in hibernate

```
http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.3/reference/en-US/html/batch.html


Session session = sessionFactory.openSession();
Transaction tx = session.beginTransaction();

for ( int i=0; i<100000; i++ ) {
  Customer customer = new Customer(.....);
  session.save(customer);
    if ( i % 20 == 0 ) { //20, same as the JDBC batch size
    //flush a batch of inserts and release memory:
    session.flush();
    session.clear();
    }
 }

tx.commit();
session.close();
```

Answer (score 0):

Fastest approach would be to use stored procedure and implement your criteria logic inside it.

But in java,you can use jdbc/hibernate.Choice depends on requirement and integration with any other framework or layers of application.

If you want a simple application to full-fill this requirement ,then go with jdbc.Otherwise to have transaction management,caching and others stuff,then go for hibernate.Hope it helps you